# How do I fix 'NativeFirebaseError: [storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.'?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have an ios mobile application in which users can upload images to an external database (Firebase Storage) and then I want the image they upload to display on a different screen. I thought I had this working but I am now getting this error:

[image: Error]

Here is the code for that screen to display the image, as you can see it's catching on line 17 `.catch(e => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));`:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {Text, View, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import TitleBar from './TitleBar';

const WardrobeScreen = () => {
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState();
  let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/' + imageURL);
  imageRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => {
      //from url you can fetch the uploaded image easily
      setImageURL(url);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
  console.log(imageURL, imageRef);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#FF6868'}}>
      <TitleBar
        pageName="Wardrobe"
        heading="Your Wardrobe"
        subHeading="So much to choose from, and space for even more!"
        backgroundColour="#FF6868"
      />

      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Text>
          Your wardrobe items will go here and scroll down depending on how many
          you have. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
          do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </Text>
        <Image source={imageURL} style={styles.image} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
});

export default WardrobeScreen;
```

I added on line 18:  `console.log(imageURL, imageRef);` and the output is:
[image]

This is my screen from which I upload images to firebase:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import TitleBar from './TitleBar';

export default function UploadScreen() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = {uri: response?.uri};
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const {uri} = image;
    let task; //  Add this
    if (uri) {
      const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      const uploadUri =
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
      setUploading(true);
      setTransferred(0);
      task = storage().ref(filename).putFile(uploadUri);
      // set progress state
      task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        setTransferred(
          Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000,
        );
      });
    }
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!',
    );
    setImage('');
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#FF6868'}}>
      <TitleBar
        pageName="Build"
        heading="Add To Your Wardrobe"
        subHeading="Choose one of the options below and build your virtual wardrobe!"
        backgroundColour="#FF6868"
      />
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={selectImage}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          {image !== '' && image !== undefined && (
            <Image source={{uri: image?.uri}} style={styles.imageBox} />
          )}
          {uploading ? (
            <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
              <Progress.Bar progress={transferred} width={300} />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  selectButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  selectButton2: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  uploadButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ffb6b9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  progressBarContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  imageBox: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
});
```

This is my firebase storage as well as an example of one of the images stored:
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong here for it to be giving this error? I'm not sure why it isn't referencing properly?

Comment: The error message is telling you that the image doesn't exist at the path you provided.  But since we can't see exactly what that path is, and we can't see the contents of your storage bucket, there's nothing we can do to help.  You will need to update your question to explain what exactly is not working the way you expect with enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the situation.

Comment: Any more understandable?

Comment: Not really.  We still can't see the value of imageUrl, and if that is the path of an existing file in your storage bucket.  You need to do some debugging to figure out if the value is what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, I added a console.log(imageURL, imageRef); and screenshot the results ^^^

Comment: No good? Still can't figure out how to retrieve the image... firebase seemingly very complicated to work with

Comment: @OllieTrute, may i please see the rules defined on your storage cloud? i think i might be able to help you if you still have not found a solution yet